Find the right interpolation method for multi-dimensional data set
I have tried "LinearNDInterpolator" from scipy.interpolate. The only data I have to validate is another set of interpolated points from another method used in Matlab (interpn), but the goal is not  to match the result Matlab's method. I also don't have examples of datasets with more than 4 dimensions to test. The goal is to find a interpolator subject to these constraints:

python 3.9
it must work with 2D datasets and higher dimensional datasets (up to 10 dimensions)

QUESTION: So given the aforementioned constraints, which method would you use to interpolate "output"?
Below you see an example of a dataset. This one seems to be structured (is it? can it be considered as a regular grid?) but this might not be the case for other datasets.

All the points:
>>> df_out[['x', 'y', 'z', 'output']].to_dict()
{'x': {0: -8.0, 1: 8.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 20.0, 4: 36.0, 5: -8.0, 6: 8.0, 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0, 9: 36.0, 10: -8.0, 11: 8.0, 12: 10.0, 13: 20.0, 14: 36.0, 15: -8.0, 16: 8.0, 17: 10.0, 18: 20.0, 19: 36.0, 20: -8.0, 21: 8.0, 22: 10.0, 23: 20.0, 24: 36.0, 25: -8.0, 26: 8.0, 27: 10.0, 28: 20.0, 29: 36.0, 30: -8.0, 31: 8.0, 32: 10.0, 33: 20.0, 34: 36.0, 35: -8.0, 36: 8.0, 37: 10.0, 38: 20.0, 39: 36.0, 40: -8.0, 41: 8.0, 42: 10.0, 43: 20.0, 44: 36.0, 45: -8.0, 46: 8.0, 47: 10.0, 48: 20.0, 49: 36.0, 50: -8.0, 51: 8.0, 52: 10.0, 53: 20.0, 54: 36.0, 55: -8.0, 56: 8.0, 57: 10.0, 58: 20.0, 59: 36.0}, 'y': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.4, 6: 0.4, 7: 0.4, 8: 0.4, 9: 0.4, 10: 0.8, 11: 0.8, 12: 0.8, 13: 0.8, 14: 0.8, 15: 0.0, 16: 0.0, 17: 0.0, 18: 0.0, 19: 0.0, 20: 0.4, 21: 0.4, 22: 0.4, 23: 0.4, 24: 0.4, 25: 0.8, 26: 0.8, 27: 0.8, 28: 0.8, 29: 0.8, 30: 0.0, 31: 0.0, 32: 0.0, 33: 0.0, 34: 0.0, 35: 0.4, 36: 0.4, 37: 0.4, 38: 0.4, 39: 0.4, 40: 0.8, 41: 0.8, 42: 0.8, 43: 0.8, 44: 0.8, 45: 0.0, 46: 0.0, 47: 0.0, 48: 0.0, 49: 0.0, 50: 0.4, 51: 0.4, 52: 0.4, 53: 0.4, 54: 0.4, 55: 0.8, 56: 0.8, 57: 0.8, 58: 0.8, 59: 0.8}, 'z': {0: -25.0, 1: -25.0, 2: -25.0, 3: -25.0, 4: -25.0, 5: -25.0, 6: -25.0, 7: -25.0, 8: -25.0, 9: -25.0, 10: -25.0, 11: -25.0, 12: -25.0, 13: -25.0, 14: -25.0, 15: -10.0, 16: -10.0, 17: -10.0, 18: -10.0, 19: -10.0, 20: -10.0, 21: -10.0, 22: -10.0, 23: -10.0, 24: -10.0, 25: -10.0, 26: -10.0, 27: -10.0, 28: -10.0, 29: -10.0, 30: 0.0, 31: 0.0, 32: 0.0, 33: 0.0, 34: 0.0, 35: 0.0, 36: 0.0, 37: 0.0, 38: 0.0, 39: 0.0, 40: 0.0, 41: 0.0, 42: 0.0, 43: 0.0, 44: 0.0, 45: 15.0, 46: 15.0, 47: 15.0, 48: 15.0, 49: 15.0, 50: 15.0, 51: 15.0, 52: 15.0, 53: 15.0, 54: 15.0, 55: 15.0, 56: 15.0, 57: 15.0, 58: 15.0, 59: 15.0}, 'output': {0: -0.02, 1: -0.02, 2: -0.02, 3: -0.1, 4: -0.11, 5: -0.02, 6: -0.02, 7: -0.02, 8: -0.1, 9: -0.11, 10: -0.02, 11: -0.02, 12: -0.02, 13: -0.1, 14: -0.11, 15: -0.018, 16: -0.018, 17: -0.018, 18: -0.1, 19: -0.1, 20: -0.018, 21: -0.018, 22: -0.018, 23: -0.1, 24: -0.1, 25: -0.018, 26: -0.018, 27: -0.018, 28: -0.1, 29: -0.1, 30: -0.014, 31: -0.014, 32: -0.014, 33: -0.09, 34: -0.09, 35: -0.014, 36: 0.014, 37: -0.014, 38: -0.09, 39: -0.09, 40: -0.014, 41: -0.0184, 42: -0.014, 43: -0.09, 44: -0.09, 45: -0.014, 46: -0.014, 47: -0.014, 48: -0.09, 49: -0.09, 50: -0.014, 51: 0.014, 52: -0.014, 53: -0.09, 54: -0.09, 55: -0.014, 56: -0.0184, 57: -0.014, 58: -0.09, 59: -0.09}}

This is the code that I have used to interpolate "output" and to produce the plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import LinearNDInterpolator

# Load the data to a dataframe "df_out"
test_nd = LinearNDInterpolator(points=df_out[['x', 'y', 'z']], values=df_out.output)
# Interpolate output
print(f'output = {test_nd(13, 0.5, -20)}')

df_out['area'] = 50
fig = plt.figure()
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
sp = ax.scatter(df_out.x, df_out.y, df_out.z, s=df_out.area, c=df_out.output, cmap=cm)
ax.set_xlabel('x data')
ax.set_ylabel('y data')
ax.set_zlabel('z data')
fig.colorbar(sp, label='output')
plt.show(block=True)

Thank you very much for your help!

"Using the data set below and python 3.9, which method would you use to interpolate output?" It depends on my goal. If the goal is to match Matlab's interpolation result, then you should include the Matlab code used to interpolate the values. If the goal is something else, you should include that in the question. Keep in mind that there are multiple algorithms for interpolating between data points, which give different results. Just because two different algorithms give different results doesn't mean that one of them is wrong.

Thanks for the guidance. I modified the post accordingly.


it must work with 2D datasets and higher dimensional datasets (up to 10 dimensions)

That doesn't narrow it down a great deal. Many of the interpolators in SciPy work in an arbitrary number of dimensions. With the exception of interpolators specifically for 1D or 2D data, all of them cope with arbitrary numbers of dimensions.
But given the dataset here, one of the interpolators that would work is scipy.interpolate.interpn().
Unfortunately, it expects its data in a different format than what you have.
You have a format like this:
x y out
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4

But interpn is expecting a format like this:
  x 0 1
y
0   1 2
1   3 4

To convert between formats, you could try something like this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy


df = pd.DataFrame({'x': {0: -8.0, 1: 8.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 20.0, 4: 36.0, 5: -8.0, 6: 8.0, 7: 10.0, 8: 20.0, 9: 36.0, 10: -8.0, 11: 8.0, 12: 10.0, 13: 20.0, 14: 36.0, 15: -8.0, 16: 8.0, 17: 10.0, 18: 20.0, 19: 36.0, 20: -8.0, 21: 8.0, 22: 10.0, 23: 20.0, 24: 36.0, 25: -8.0, 26: 8.0, 27: 10.0, 28: 20.0, 29: 36.0, 30: -8.0, 31: 8.0, 32: 10.0, 33: 20.0, 34: 36.0, 35: -8.0, 36: 8.0, 37: 10.0, 38: 20.0, 39: 36.0, 40: -8.0, 41: 8.0, 42: 10.0, 43: 20.0, 44: 36.0, 45: -8.0, 46: 8.0, 47: 10.0, 48: 20.0, 49: 36.0, 50: -8.0, 51: 8.0, 52: 10.0, 53: 20.0, 54: 36.0, 55: -8.0, 56: 8.0, 57: 10.0, 58: 20.0, 59: 36.0}, 'y': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.4, 6: 0.4, 7: 0.4, 8: 0.4, 9: 0.4, 10: 0.8, 11: 0.8, 12: 0.8, 13: 0.8, 14: 0.8, 15: 0.0, 16: 0.0, 17: 0.0, 18: 0.0, 19: 0.0, 20: 0.4, 21: 0.4, 22: 0.4, 23: 0.4, 24: 0.4, 25: 0.8, 26: 0.8, 27: 0.8, 28: 0.8, 29: 0.8, 30: 0.0, 31: 0.0, 32: 0.0, 33: 0.0, 34: 0.0, 35: 0.4, 36: 0.4, 37: 0.4, 38: 0.4, 39: 0.4, 40: 0.8, 41: 0.8, 42: 0.8, 43: 0.8, 44: 0.8, 45: 0.0, 46: 0.0, 47: 0.0, 48: 0.0, 49: 0.0, 50: 0.4, 51: 0.4, 52: 0.4, 53: 0.4, 54: 0.4, 55: 0.8, 56: 0.8, 57: 0.8, 58: 0.8, 59: 0.8}, 'z': {0: -25.0, 1: -25.0, 2: -25.0, 3: -25.0, 4: -25.0, 5: -25.0, 6: -25.0, 7: -25.0, 8: -25.0, 9: -25.0, 10: -25.0, 11: -25.0, 12: -25.0, 13: -25.0, 14: -25.0, 15: -10.0, 16: -10.0, 17: -10.0, 18: -10.0, 19: -10.0, 20: -10.0, 21: -10.0, 22: -10.0, 23: -10.0, 24: -10.0, 25: -10.0, 26: -10.0, 27: -10.0, 28: -10.0, 29: -10.0, 30: 0.0, 31: 0.0, 32: 0.0, 33: 0.0, 34: 0.0, 35: 0.0, 36: 0.0, 37: 0.0, 38: 0.0, 39: 0.0, 40: 0.0, 41: 0.0, 42: 0.0, 43: 0.0, 44: 0.0, 45: 15.0, 46: 15.0, 47: 15.0, 48: 15.0, 49: 15.0, 50: 15.0, 51: 15.0, 52: 15.0, 53: 15.0, 54: 15.0, 55: 15.0, 56: 15.0, 57: 15.0, 58: 15.0, 59: 15.0}, 'output': {0: -0.02, 1: -0.02, 2: -0.02, 3: -0.1, 4: -0.11, 5: -0.02, 6: -0.02, 7: -0.02, 8: -0.1, 9: -0.11, 10: -0.02, 11: -0.02, 12: -0.02, 13: -0.1, 14: -0.11, 15: -0.018, 16: -0.018, 17: -0.018, 18: -0.1, 19: -0.1, 20: -0.018, 21: -0.018, 22: -0.018, 23: -0.1, 24: -0.1, 25: -0.018, 26: -0.018, 27: -0.018, 28: -0.1, 29: -0.1, 30: -0.014, 31: -0.014, 32: -0.014, 33: -0.09, 34: -0.09, 35: -0.014, 36: 0.014, 37: -0.014, 38: -0.09, 39: -0.09, 40: -0.014, 41: -0.0184, 42: -0.014, 43: -0.09, 44: -0.09, 45: -0.014, 46: -0.014, 47: -0.014, 48: -0.09, 49: -0.09, 50: -0.014, 51: 0.014, 52: -0.014, 53: -0.09, 54: -0.09, 55: -0.014, 56: -0.0184, 57: -0.014, 58: -0.09, 59: -0.09}})


def dataset_to_dense(df, index_cols, value_col):
    points = []
    # Find all distinct values within index_cols.
    for col in index_cols:
        # Index must be sorted for np.searchsorted() later
        ordered_index = sorted(df[col].unique())
        points.append(np.array(ordered_index))
    values = np.full([len(points_array) for points_array in points], np.nan)
    value_indices = []
    # For each column, convert column values to array indices
    for i, col in enumerate(index_cols):
        values_along_index = points[i]
        column_values = df[col].values
        # Note: this assumes that values_along_index contains all values within this col.
        # Otherwise indices will be off by one
        column_index = np.searchsorted(values_along_index, column_values)
        # Sanity check: does indexing into points[i] with this new index produce the
        # same results as the original column?
        assert (values_along_index[column_index] == column_values).all(), \
            f"could not find all elements of {col} in indexer"
        value_indices.append(column_index)
    # Set values of array at indices found in previous step
    values[tuple(value_indices)] = df[value_col]
    return points, values
    

def interpolate_dataset(df, index_cols, value_col, xi):
    points, values = dataset_to_dense(df, index_cols, value_col)
    return scipy.interpolate.interpn(points, values, xi)


xi = [
    (13, 0.5, -20),
    (35, 0, 0),
]
interpolated = interpolate_dataset(df, ['x', 'y', 'z'], 'output', xi)
print(interpolated)

Notes:

xi represents the points to query the interpolation at.

